# Tornado PipeIOStream: OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Tags: python, tornado

I've a little micro webservice which stores messages locally identified by IDs. To ensure that files won't be written at the same time, I've implemented a queue. The following code works just once, a second file upload throws traceback below, I really don't know how to handle the fd correctly.

```
from tornado import web, ioloop, gen
from tornado.queues import Queue
from tornado.iostream import PipeIOStream

class Sample:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = Queue()

    @gen.coroutine
    def write_queue(self):
        while True:
            item = yield self.queue.get()
            print("Message with id %s stored" % item[0])
            fd = open(item[0], 'ab')
            stream = PipeIOStream(fd.fileno())
            yield stream.write(item[1])
            stream.close_fd()

class MainHandler(web.RequestHandler):

    def initialize(self, store):
        self.store = store

    @gen.coroutine
    def put(self, id):
        yield self.store.queue.put((id, self.request.body))


def start(store):
    return web.Application([
        (r"/(.*)", MainHandler,
         {"store": store})
    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    store = Store()
    app = start(store)
    app.listen(8888)
    ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_callback(store.write_queue)
    ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()




ERROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback functools.partial(<function wrap.<locals>.null_wrapper at 0x7f46657f46a8>, <Future finished exception=OSError(9, 'Bad file descriptor')>)
Traceback (most recent call last):

    stream = PipeIOStream(fd.fileno())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 1643, in __init__
    self._fio = io.FileIO(self.fd, "r+")
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The file descriptor returned by `open` is not a pipe. It's generally legal to use regular files with `PipeIOStream`, but it's not *useful* on linux. Such file descriptors are always considered readable, and reading from them or writing to them always blocks. So using PipeIOStream like this is no better than simply doing `fd.write(item[1])`.
2. You've opened the file in write-only mode, but PipeIOStream wraps its file in a read/write wrapper (I'm actually kind of surprised that this ever works, since real pipes are one-way). I *think* that's where this exception is coming from. If you opened the file in `'ab+'` mode, I think it would work. I haven't tried this, though.

Comment: 1. As far as I know working with queues in order to write serialized will block anyway, I'll not use PipeIOStream anymore as aforementioned example won't be useful nor work at all. 2. 'ab+' also don't work.